# Add a control programmatically to a DocumentContent (AvalonDock)

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

I have a DocumentContent (AvalonDock) which contains a textEditor. I want to add a toolbar to it at runtime. To do this I need to add a GridDefinition so that the first row has a fixed height (for the toolbar) and the rest of the document content should be filled by the texteditor.

I created a new Grid and added a row definition to it and added the child to it but I don't know how to attach this to the DocumentContent. I am not even sure if it is the right way to add the toolbar. Any suggestions ?

```
        Grid grid = new Grid();
        RowDefinition rowDefinition1 = new RowDefinition();
        rowDefinition1.Height = new GridLength(32);

        grid.RowDefinitions.Insert(0, rowDefinition1);
        grid.Children.Insert(0, new IsaDocToolbar());
```

PS: I forgot to mention that I use AvalonDock 1.3

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this in code and not using XAML?

Here is the basic idea/concept using MVVM in XAML

Document content should be a grid with 2 rows
1st row for toolbar
2nd row for text editor

Visibility of the first row can be controlled using binding to a Boolean property and by using BoolToVisibilityConverter.

Hope this helps. I have been doing something similar (not on the document content) for the application. You can checkout my [Wide project](https://github.com/chandramouleswaran/Wide) for a similar concept for toolbars for the window.